# Expected number of dice rolls

Tags: statistics

Say I have a 100 sided die.

If I have target rolls of:

- A = roll a 1  (1/100)
- B = roll a 2 or a 3  (1/50)
- C = roll a 4,5,6 or 7 (1/25)

What is my expected number of rolls to achieve all of my targets at least once?

Is there a generic formula/process for solving this with different targets/die?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Backwards induction is a good standard method.

Sketch:

Consider states determined by the good events that have already happened.  Thus a state is a subset of $\{A,B,C\}$.  For any state $S$ let $E_S$ be the expected number of turns it will take to finish given that all the events in $S$ (and no other good events) have occurred.  The answer you want is $E_{\emptyset}$.

Easy to see that $$E_{A,B}= 25\quad \quad E_{A,C}=50\quad \quad  E_{B,C}=100$$

Now consider, say, $E_A$.  Considering the next toss, we see that $$E_A=1+\frac 1{50}E_{A,B}+\frac {1}{25}E_{A,C}+\left(1-\frac 1{50}-\frac 1{25}\right)E_A$$

And similarly for $E_B, E_C$.  From those it is easy to get $E_{\emptyset}$.